# Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop Auto-Install using Preseed

Tags: grub2, 22.04, iso, customization, isolinux

We've a customise OS on top of Ubuntu 18.04 desktop, we are trying to upgrade the Ubuntu version to 22.04.

We have preseed files where we have defined auto-install process. I am trying to find a way to do the auto install in same way as it did with Ubuntu 18.04. Have found many resources but unfortunately all were related to making auto install Ubuntu Server using cloud init. And I don't want to use cloud-init with server version then install desktop on top of it.

My questions are-

- Can we perform auto install using preseed in Ubuntu 22.02 (I guess we can do this in desktop version as I've seen preseed file exist while extracting the Ubuntu 22.04 desktop).
- If it's possible to do with preseed then where do I define `isolinux/txt.cfg` configuration as `isolinux` directory doesn't exist in Ubuntu 22.04 desktop version.

PS: I am very new to this, excuse me if I am making any mistake here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use d-i and preseeding on 22.04 to automate installations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403601/how-to-use-d-i-and-preseeding-on-22-04-to-automate-installations)